# Nested brackets in html/Angular

Tags: html, angularjs, pug

I'm currently stuck trying to access a value in jade from Angular. The simple code snippet is shown below:

```
td(ng-repeat="part in part_arr")
  {{part_obj_val[{{part}}]["percentage"]}}
```

When I replace {{part}} with the value it outputs, it works but when I replace the value with {{parts}}, it does not work. Any ideas?

Edit: can be explained in html or jade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use interpolation, pass it in as a variable the same way you do with any javascript

```
{{part_obj_val[part]["percentage"]}}
```